# How to make 0 return true?

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I am searching for something in an array, and if a value is found, I do something. I am doing this by setting a variable to undefined, and then when the value is found, setting to the index of the element found. This would work if the value returned is anything but 0, but if it is 0, then it returns as false. How can I work around this?

```
var index = undefined;
for(var i=0; i<ARRAY; i++)
{
  if(CONDITION)
     index = i;
}
if(index)
{
  DO SOMETHING
}
```

So my problem occurred when the index turned out to be zero, because this returned false. The reason I want to do it this way is because I am not sure if it exists in the array or not.

Comment: Show your testcase, and define all these "something"s.

Comment: @Topener: No, it's not; however, both are falsey.

Comment: @hbtest are you sure you don't just want to use the [indexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function?

Comment: Wow! Thats exactly what I needed and wanted. I am not too familiar with javascript so I didn't know it existed

Comment: Actually it didn't work, I needed a property from one of the objects in array to match, not an object directly in array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean you have a variable that may be `undefined` or some number, and you want `undefined` to be distinguishable from `0`?

Then:

```
if (index)      // wrong
if (index >= 0) // right
```

Or you can use type-aware comparisons:

```
if (index !== undefined) { .. }
```

Comment: This solves my problem, but after looking at the other answers, I realized I was over-complicating this. I could just use the java way of -1.

Comment: @hbtest: Sure, you could do that too. It's not the answer to _this_ question, but it would avoid the initial issue altogether. FWIW, I'd use `undefined`: it's more "distant" from the positive numbers than is `-1` and thus feels more appropriate to me for use as a non-index sentinel.

Comment: I was planning on accepting yours, but it was too soon to accept an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Why not be 100% explicit? This is, after all, what you're actually intending to check:

```
if (typeof index === 'number')
{
  // DO SOMETHING
}
```

I prefer this even to checking `>= 0` since that operator gives some weird results for non-numeric values:

```
Input | >= 0
------------
"1"   | true
false | true
null  | true
[]    | true
""    | true
```

(See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HHuZL/) for evidence.)

Answer (score 8):

How about testing the result to see whether it's `>= 0` instead of relying on its truthyness?

```
if (index >= 0) { ... }
```

The `undefined` value is **not** `>= 0` so that should work.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the short and simple way of doing what I wanted. I am new to javascript, so I was trying to use it's fancy tricks, but I guess if it isn't broke, then don't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`0` is falsey in javascript; use `===` to test whether a value is actually false:

```
foo = 0;
foo == false //true
foo === false //false
```

As you're setting the value to `undefined` one way of testing is to see whether the value is Not a Number:

```
if (!isNaN(foo))
{
  //foo is numeric
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the OP said the other elements are `undefined`, not `false` (though he could obviously just as easily use `false` as `undefined`).

Comment: @DanTao, the original question has been changed significantly since when I first posted my brief answer.

Comment: @zzzzBov: No, it's said "`undefined`" since it was first posted.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, you're right, i'm wrong. I was confused by the line "This would work if the value returned is anything but 0, but if it is 0, then it returns as false". In any event, I've updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use -1 to indicate the index was not found in the array.  As you mentioned, 0 will be implicitly cast to a "false" if you use it like a boolean.  You can use === to avoid an implicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

You could... not do it like that, because you need to work within JS's definition of truthiness, or check explicitly for `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote these simple utility functions to help with more math-oriented tasks:

```
function isFalsy(val) {
    return (((!val)&&(val!==0))||(val === null)||(val === NaN)||(val === ""))
}

function isTruthy(val) {
    return !isFalsy(val)
}
```